# Translate font size to axes units

Tags: python, matplotlib, text

How to convert font size to axes size?

Minimal example: how to find `fontSize`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
    plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 22})
    plt.rcParams.update({'font.family': 'serif'})
    plt.rcParams.update({'text.usetex': True})

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    fontSize = 0.05
    ax.text( 0.25, 0.5, "Text A", va = "center")
    ax.text( 0.25, 0.5 + fontSize, "Text B", va = "center")

    fig.canvas.draw()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image: Result graphic]

I want to use it automatically so I cannot simply change it manually – I want to know if the text above overlaps the text below.